# Open source distributed computing/cloud computing frameworks

Tags: distributed, cloud

I was wondering if anyone knows of any good Open Source distributed computing projects?  I have a computationally intensive program that could benefit from distributed computing (a la SETI@Home, etc.) and want to know if anyone has seen such a thing or will I be developing it from scratch?

Comment: Funny, last night I was mulling over how cool it would be to have a P2P distributed computing network that anyone could submit jobs to. Would be a ripe target for abuse obviously, but might be interesting. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [one](http://www.gridgain.com/) for java and [one](http://ngrid.sourceforge.net/) for c# and here's an open source grid [toolkit](http://www.globus.org/).

Answer (score 3):

I see that this is over a year old but this is a new and relevant answer

http://openstack.org/

Answer (score 2):

SETI@Home uses [BOINC](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/)

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop if you want to run the machines yourself. Amazon Elastic MapReduce if you want to let others run your workers. Amazon Elastic MapReduce is based on Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

MPAPI - Parallel and Distributed Applications Framework.

- Sector 0 Article:
  http://sector0.dk/?page_id=15.
- Gives a good overview of the
  framework, architecture and the
  theory behind it.
- Works on a single machine to 'n'
  machines.
- Design distributed logic into the
  system.
- Focuses on message passing to isolate
  the state that each thread has access
  to i.e. no shared state only
  messages.
- Is Open Source =] and is MONO
  Compatible YAY!

**Architecture in a Nutshell**

***Cluster***

- Single Main Node
- Controls the cluster
- Numerous Sub-Nodes (one per machine) which are the work horses of the cluster
- Single Registration Server - Binds the cluster together by allowing nodes to register / unregister with cluster notifying
  existing nodes

***Communication***

- Node to Node directly. Each worker
  communicates with others through the
  node.
- The messages are not
  propagated down through the remoting
  layer unless two workers are on
  different nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally used [BOINC](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/) which is a robust solution, widely used and offer you a great range of possibilities in term of customization.
This is the most complete solution I know. The only problems I had were that it was difficult to use for remote job submission (if you don't have access to the server) and it can be a bit long to setup. But overall it is a very good solution.

If you rather want to implement distributed computing just over a local grid, you can use [GridCompute](http://gridcompute.readthedocs.org) that should be quick to set up and will let you use your application through python scripts.

PS: I am the developer of GridCompute.